# Perl Cannot Find/Reload File

Tags: html, perl

I have a submit.html file that prints calculations done in a file called Observation.pm. Observation.pm exists in the folder called project. However, when the script runs, these error are printed:

Error during compilation of submit.html:Attempt to reload project/Observation.pm aborted.Compilation failed in require at submit.html line 67.

Line 67 in submit.html is:
    `use project::Observation.pm;`

For some reason, it cannot find the Observation.pm file.

I have tried deleting and adding the Observation.pm file again. I've also tried using 
    `use lib /path/name/to/project/;`
in submit.html.

Any ideas on why this is happening or how to fix it? Let me know if I left out some vital info of the problem, wasn't sure what was relevant.

Comment: Is submit.html and Observation.pm in the same directory?

Comment: No, they are in different directories.

Comment: the ".pm" shouldn't be included if you're using the package name.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use: **Observation::Attempt** instead of **Atempt** and also **use path** to the .pm file

Answer (score 0):

When you `use project::Observation;`, Perl looks in [`@INC`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%40INC) directories, if it finds an appropriate module.

In your case ([`use lib '/path/name/to/project';`](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html)), this means it looks for a module named `/path/name/to/project/project/Observation.pm`.

Note the double `.../project/project/...`. So the correct search path must include `/path/name/to` instead, e.g.

```
use lib /path/name/to;
```

or if you want/need to keep `use lib '/path/name/to/project';`, say

```
use Observation;
```

instead.

---

Also note @ChrisTurner's comment, don't add the `.pm` extension.